# Can't install craft3 using the command line. Testing database credentials ... failed:

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, laravel-valet, craftcms

After creating a project on the command line and going through the setup I get

`Testing database credentials ... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`

I am using mysql8, using laravel valet, have created a db using mysql.

Have found answers that suggest using 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost for the Database server name or IP address: . Have tried this but still isn't working.

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

mysql 8 started using a different authentication scheme than previous versions. On one machine I had that problem I changed the variable in my.cnf, restarted the server and I was ready to go.

In your mysql server config file, look at this variable:
"default_authentication_plugin".

If it says caching_sha2_password then change it to mysql_native_password

The reasoning behind this is there is no support for caching_sha2_password for the php mysqli driver. If you don't want to change the config, you'll have to wait until the driver gets updated.